# Google Maps GroundOverlay Display

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I am trying to use groundoverlay on Google Maps just to see if I can get an image on Google Maps. I have no error and looking through the documentation and examples. The image does not display.
Here is part of my code where I am implementing groundoverlay:

```
private GroundOverlay mGroundOverlay;

private static final LatLng NEWARK = new LatLng(40.714086, -74.228697);
.....
```

Under

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
.....

public void setImage(){
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(NEWARK, 11));

    mGroundOverlay = googleMap.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions()
    .image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.battery)).anchor(0, 1)
    .position(NEWARK , 85000f,6500f));
}
```

I have the image "battery.jpeg" in my resource folder, drawable-hpdi

Can some look at my code and tell me what I am missing? Since I am a beginner in Android I would like an explanation as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm reading your intention incorrectly, but if you are trying to use the Android Maps API, you'll have to get a key from the API dashboard; the irreplaceable vogella has a tutorial:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html

if you are a new droidgrammer, I can think of no better programmer to learn from.

also, could you post your logcat? FYI: you can use Logcat Extreme on a rooted device to get live logging overlaid on your device that you can also send to file... it's the bee's knees and pouring over logcat readouts will accelerate your education greatly. =]

gl hf

Comment: Well, I do have my API key working. The purpose of this question was to get GroundOverlay working or getting an image to display on Google Maps

Comment: could you post your logcat?

Answer (score 0):

Check this one

```
         LatLng c1 = new LatLng( -33.67032801,151.30209310);
         LatLng c2 = new LatLng( -33.66687426,151.30269820);
         LatLng c3 = new LatLng( -33.66657936,151.30026840);
         LatLng c4 = new LatLng( -33.67003309,151.29966320);
         LatLngBounds latLngBounds = new LatLngBounds(c1, c3).including(c2).including(c4);
         GroundOverlayOptions groundOverlayOptions = new 
                                                   GroundOverlayOptions();
        BitmapDescriptor bitmapDescriptor = 
                   BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromAsset("h1.png");
    groundOverlayOptions.image(bitmapDescriptor);
    groundOverlayOptions.positionFromBounds(latLngBounds);
    map.addGroundOverlay(groundOverlayOptions);
```